# Reading numbers to array from string

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

> i create static array, suggest would good for finding numbers in string for array size

```
(setf arr (make-array'(5))) 

(loop for i from 0 to 4
  do (if (/= nil (read-from-string str)) 
         (setq x (read-from-string str t nil :start i))
         (setf (aref arr i) x))))
```

> i want to go until end of string

Comment: `(let ((*read-eval* nil)) (read-from-string (format nil "#( ~a )" data)))`

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun string->vector (s)
  (let ((*read-eval* nil))              ;be a bit safe
    (with-input-from-string (in s)
      (loop for e = (read in nil in)
            for n upfrom 0
            until (eq e in)
            collect e into es
            finally (return (make-array n :initial-contents es))))))
```